# Application of Jensen's Formula to show sum convergence

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

Suppose $f$ is analytic and bounded on the unit disk and $f (0) \ne 0$.  Let ${s_n}$ be the zeros of $f$. Show that $\sum_n(1-|s_n|) < \infty$.

The hint given is to apply Jensen's formula to a disc of radius $R$ with $R < 1$. Clearly the hypotheses for the formula apply to f, but I'm having a hard time seeing how to relate it to the sum in question.  It'd be great if someone could point me in the right direction on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f$ be bounded by $M > 0$. For $0 < r \leq R < 1$ let  $N_r$ be the finite multi-set of zeroes of $f$ on the disc $\Delta_r$ with radius $r$ (counting multiplicity).  Then there is a holomorphic $h$,  non-vanishing on $\Delta_r$ such that $|h(z)| = |f(z)|$ for $|z| = R$ and

$$
f(z) = h(z) R^{|N_r|} \prod_{\alpha \in N_r} \frac{\alpha - z}{R^2 - \overline{\alpha} z}.
$$

By the maximum principle for $h$ the following inequality holds at $z=0$:

$$
R^{|N_r|}|f(0)| = |h(0)| \prod_{\alpha \in N_r} |\alpha| \leq \max_{|z|=R}|f(z)| \prod_{\alpha \in N_r} |\alpha| \leq M \prod_{\alpha \in N_r} |\alpha|.
$$

Since this holds for all $R \in [r, 1)$ we can take the limit $R \to 1$  to get the inequality

$$
\prod_{\alpha \in N_r} |\alpha| \geq \frac{|f(0)|}{M}
$$

for all $r \in (0, 1)$.  In particular

$$
\lim_{r \to 1} \prod_{\alpha \in N_r}\left(1 - (1 - |\alpha|) \right) = \lim_{r \to 1} \prod_{\alpha \in N_r} |\alpha| \geq \frac{|f(0)|}{M} > 0.
$$

This implies (by a well known correspondence) that

$$
\lim_{r \to 1} \sum_{\alpha \in N_r} (1 - |\alpha|) < \infty.
$$

Comment: Late comment, but where might I find a reference for this "well known correspondence"?

Comment: @MilesJohnson See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product#Convergence_criteria) for example.